Localhost routing through proxy when it should not be doing so
This is an issue a client is having. They have a proxy set up for all their web traffic but localhost (127.0.0.1) is also being incorrectly routed through the proxy. As you all know local traffic should remain in the machine. We confirmed this by running a Wireshark and the wss://bcs.visualware.com request from the browser (which resolves to 127.0.0.1) comes through as an HTTP request NOT a loopback web-socket packet like it should.
Is there a setting in the local machine that stops this from happening or is this something the proxy admin will have to resolve?

You need to add an proxy exception on the client. As you tell us nothing about the configuration, you can't get anything but general answers. In fact, telling a browser to proxy even localhost is perfectly valid.

Thanks, @vidarlo, I appreciate the comment. I am not privy to their config and it's good to know it can be a valid setting. This should be sufficient for them to take action.
